# breaking the lines while chunking into multiple files

Tags: java, file, split, chunks, srt

I am dividing my file into chunks but only problem i am facing is,

i have .srt file, but while doing chunks, it's cutting the characters i.e in first .srt file it's like 00:26:20,230 --> . in next file it continuing the next time stamp 00:27:40,343.

I need to check the timestamp to be complete and then next full subtitle sentence too. i.e if it's cutting the subtitle timesstamp or dialogue in in file, that tect to be append to next file. Please suggest me how can i achieve.

I am trying like below,

```
    String FilePath = "/Users/meh/Desktop/escapeplan.srt";
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(FilePath);

        System.out.println("size: " +fin.getChannel().size());
        long abc = 0l;
        abc = (fin.getChannel().size())/3;
        System.out.println("6: " +abc);
System.out.println("abc: " +abc);
       //FilePath = args[1];
        File filename = new File(FilePath);
        long splitFileSize = 0,bytefileSize=0;
        if (filename.exists()) {
            try {
                //bytefileSize = Long.parseLong(args[2]);
                splitFileSize = abc;
                Splitme spObj = new Splitme();
                spObj.split(FilePath, (long) splitFileSize);
                spObj = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("File Not Found....");
        }

    public void split(String FilePath, long splitlen) {

            long leninfile = 0, leng = 0;
            int count = 1, data;
            try {
                File filename = new File(FilePath);
                InputStream infile = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
                data = infile.read();
                System.out.println("data");
                System.out.println(data);

                while (data != -1) {
                    filename = new File("/Users/meh/Documents/srt" + count + ".srt");
    //RandomAccessFile outfile = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "rw");

                    OutputStream outfile = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
                    while (data != -1 && leng < splitlen) {
                        outfile.write(data);
                        leng++;
                        data = infile.read();
                    }
                    leninfile += leng;
                    leng = 0;
                    outfile.close();
                    changeTimeStamp(filename, count);

                    count++;


                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

i am trying to check the time stamp is in correct format or not. Then i need to check next line to be a dialogue and then the next line to be empty line. then it can stop chunk or else it should append the text from the previous chunk to next chunk file in the beginning of line . so that it may get in correct format.

I tried checking the format like,

```
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] atoms = strLine.split(" --> ");
                if (atoms.length == 1) {
                    out.write(strLine + "\n");

                } else {

                    String startTS = atoms[0];
                    String endTS = atoms[1];
                    System.out.print("sri atmos start" + startTS);
                    System.out.print("sri atmos end" + endTS);
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss,SSS");

                    sdf.setLenient(false);
                    try
                    {
                        sdf.parse(startTS);
                        sdf.parse(endTS);
                        System.out.println("Valid time");
                        System.out.println("File path" + srcFileNm);
}
                    catch(Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Invalid time");
                        System.out.println("Exception start" + startTS);
                        System.out.println("Exception end" + endTS);
}
}
```

some screens of my output chunks,
[image]
[image]

Help me how can i make this possible.

Comment: Try using the debugger and adding a breakpoint during your 2nd while loop, so you can see how the data is being processed

Comment: But confused how to check the file should start from the full time format then next a full dialogue and then an empty line. That's why posted here now :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change approach, and fully use basic I/O methods. I tried to encapsulate logic in a small class, that produces a triple with id, msecs and a list of subtitles (if I'm not wrong, you can have more than a line). Then I leaved the remainder externally. Chunker is a class that reads a triple (class Three) from file, so that you can manage it and write it somewhere.
This is just a "quick&dirty" idea that you can refine, but it should work.

```
package org.norsam.stackoverflow;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Chunker
{

    BufferedReader r;
    int chunk = 0;
    File dir;

    public Chunker(File dir, String filename) throws IOException
    {
        File f = new File(dir, filename);
        this.dir = dir;
        this.r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    }

    public Three readThree() throws IOException
    {
        Integer id = Integer.parseInt(r.readLine());
        String msecs = r.readLine();
        String s = null;
        List<String> srt = new ArrayList<>();
        while (!(s = r.readLine().trim()).isEmpty()) {
            srt.add(s);
        }
        return new Three(id, msecs, srt);
    }

    class Three
    {
        Integer id;
        String msecs;
        List<String> srts;

        Three(Integer id, String msecs, List<String> srts)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.msecs = msecs;
            this.srts = srts;
        }

        Three doSomething() {
            // here you can do something with your data,
            // e.g. split msecs on "-->" and check times
            return this;
        }
        void write(BufferedWriter r) throws IOException
        {
            r.write(id);
            r.newLine();
            r.write(msecs);
            r.newLine();
            for (String s : srts) {
                r.write(s);
                r.newLine();
            }
            r.newLine();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String baseDir = "/dir/where/resides/srt";
        String filename = "filename.srt";
        int elemPerChunk = 50;
        int fileNum = 0;
        File dir = new File(baseDir);
        Chunker chunker = new Chunker(dir, filename);
        boolean completed = false;
        while (!completed) {
            int srtCount = 0;
            File f = new File(baseDir, "ch." + (fileNum++) + "." + filename);
            BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
            try {
                while (srtCount++ < elemPerChunk) {
                    chunker.readThree().doSomething().write(w);
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                completed = true;
            }
            w.close();
        }
    }
}
```